# Connect to host error

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to understand how network in `Qt` works. I wrote simple client and server and it works fine when as host i use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. But how can i connect to server if it's running on the another computer? I tried to write `IP` address like `97.121.34.5` but it doesn't work. What should i do?

Server:

```
Server::Server(int port, QWidget *pwgt): QWidget(pwgt), block(0)
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Server Error", "Unable to start the server: " + server->errorString());
        return;
    }
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(slotNewConnection()));
    edit = new QTextEdit;
    edit->setReadOnly(true);

    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(new QLabel("<H1>Server</H1>"));
    lay->addWidget(edit);
    this->setLayout(lay);
}
```

Client:

```
Client::Client(const QString &host, int port, QWidget *pwgt): QWidget(pwgt), block(0)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost(host, port);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(slotConnected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(slotError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    edit = new QTextEdit;
    input = new QLineEdit;

    edit->setReadOnly(true);

    QPushButton *send = new QPushButton("Send");
    connect(send, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotSendToServer()));
    connect(input, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(slotSendToServer()));

    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(new QLabel("<H1>Client</H1>"));
    lay->addWidget(edit);
    lay->addWidget(input);
    lay->addWidget(send);
    this->setLayout(lay);
}
```

Thanks.

P.S. If needed i can post the whole code of my program.

Comment: Try to call `socket->connectToHost(host, port);` after you establish connections such as `connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works on `localhost` then you don't have any problem with the program. I think the problem is that you don't know your network well... For example if your server is behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) you won't be able to reach it. It is possible that the `IP` you are trying to connect to is the `IP` of the computer inside the internal network and not the outer internet.
This is a tricky problem, I think, because no one knows your network.

What you need is to know the real `IP` address of your server. If you have a router, all the computers connected to that router will get an `IP` from that router which is valid only inside that network. This means that if you have pay your `ISP` for an `IP` address e.g. `89.64.123.3` and you want to connect to internet with all your computers in the house, you need to buy a router, connect the router to internet through that IP address i.e. `89.64.123.3` and then connect with all the computers in the house to that router. When you connect with all the computers in the house to that router, every computer gets an `IP` from that router e.g. `192.168.1.0`, `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.9`, etc.

[image]

Now if your `server` is on one of these computers which are connected to that router and the `client` tries to connect to that server using one of the internal `IP` addresses i.e. `192.168.1.0`, `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.9`, etc. you will have a surprise because those IP addresses are not visible from the internet. Even the client wants to connect to the server to the IP address of the router i.e. `89.64.123.3` won't work because the router doesn't know to which computer of the internal network to forward the [`TCP` frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure). In this case you would want to setup and configure a [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) host(although I won't bet my money that this is the right way to do it as I'm not a guru in this field - if someone knows I'm speaking crap, please correct me). This way when a packet arrives to the `IP` address of the router, the router forwards it to the computer you configured the the router to send it to. Configuring a `DMZ` host for a router depends on the router model and you should find instructions on the internet for that.

I recommend reading [Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132856204) for more a deeper understanding of how networks work.

Comment: Wow.. Actually what i want is to sed server.exe to someone and connect to it through the client. Is it possible?

Comment: @IvanovIvan As I said, it depends on the the network the computer running the server runs on. If the IP of that computer is an IP visible from the internet, than it should work. If it is behind a router I think he should setup a DMZ(although as I said, I'm not 100% sure if this is the right way to do it as my experience with DMZ is little - this is how I setup my webserver at home). If he is behind a NAT I think you're out of luck. If your friend's computer is directly connected to internet, then your client should connect ok to the IP of your friend(www.whatismyip.com should tell him his IP)

Comment: @IvanovIvan Regarding servers behind NAT: it is possible but it requires a bit of work: http://superuser.com/questions/121435/is-it-possible-to-host-a-web-server-from-behind-a-nat

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash or expect script for this contest.
Using QProcess u can call these script and using this script you can easily connect with any ip using telnet or shh and also you can send and receive what actually u want..
i think your problem is what - You want to connect with another machine which has an ip like 97.121.34.5
U can use expect scripting its very easy 
Example

```
QString program = "/opt/expect5.45/expect"; // this is your expect .exe path


           QStringList arguments;

           arguments <<"/tmp/ppc/example.exp"<<ip;// ipboard is ip address of the system that u want to connect with

           myProcess->startDetached(program, arguments),QIODevice::ReadWrite;

           QString datas= myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
```

Your expect script looks like:

```
#!/home/student/expect -f
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0] // ip address coming from your front end 

spawn telnet arg1 //ip telneting to your server system
expect "login: "
send "your loginname\r" // pass your login name here
expect "Password: "
send "password\r" // send password here 
expect "~$ "
send "something u want\r" // send what u want to exicute
expect "~$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Please learn how to use expect and what is expect script it will improve your answer..
for using expect you must install it